# Similar activities in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I would want to make two similar activities in android. If i change something in one, the changes appear simultaneously in the other. So it's as if they were a constant copy of each other. Is it possible to do that in Android ? Thank you to everyone !

Comment: How would a change appear simultaneously in both? 99% of the time only one Activity is visible at a time. As for communicating the change in a more typical fashion- I would either use a [`SharedPreference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or pass the value via the Activities' Intents.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at abstract classes http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html. Essentially, you make one class that does all the commonly shared logic, and have each child class extend that. That way you make your code changes once. Hopefully I understood your question correctly. Please comment if not.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. In fact, let's say we have an activity that we call activity1. And let's say we have another activity that we call activity2 which is a child of activity1. Let's say they have exactly the same code. Ok. But what I would want is that : in my android smartphone, if i do something in activity1 physically with my fingers (for example write something on a field), the text I've written must also appear in the same field in activity2 simultaneously. They have to to be synced. And the fact that they have the same code does not permit that, I think. What do you think ? Thank

Comment: I guess I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to accomplish. Maybe a better explanation of your total goal would help. The only reason you would need to have live syncing between activities is if you were displaying them at the same time, which as far as I know, is not possible.

Comment: Ok,i'll try to explain the context. In reality, we work on a project. We already have a vocal application (you can dialogue with the application). The goal is to create a tactile application to be synced with that vocal application. To simplify things at the beginning, we just wanted to simulate both applications (tactile and vocal) with two activities. And one of those would represent the vocal application. Every time, the user has the possibility to do something either via the vocal application (by talking), either via the tactile application (by typing)...(see below)

Comment: In our simple version, as we can not represent the vocal application, we'll just represent it as an activity. And as the user can always do something either vocally either graphically, the activities have to be the same and the changes in one have to appear simultaneously in the other. I know it's quite strange. And in fact, I don't think we'll proceed like that. But thank you very much for your participation.